# I can't access a kubernetes service from localhost

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-dashboard

I've recently been learning Docker and Kubernetes. I think i now understand docker pretty well so ive been trying to make the kubernetes work. I'm on Windows btw.

I have installed kubernetes with the standard windows docker dashboard and done everything that was in the tutorials I've found to get the kubernetes dashboard.

Now I have my dashboard and I'm running a simple nginx pod.

[image]

with a service :

[image]

but when I go on localhost:88 it tells me that localhost hasnt sent any data.

I have also tried :

```cmd
kubectl port-forward nginx-67d74d8fbc-qnzgf :88
```

and when I tried in the port that was assigned automatically it said inaccessible website and did this error in the cmd:

```
Handling connection for 58193
Handling connection for 58193
E0523 12:49:36.846094   16200 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 58193 -> 
88: error forwarding port 88 to pod  764194941a96bf6dc7b3d491ffe910cd34885e20a0b98690392b9a4c4feca310, uid : exit status 1: 
2022/05/23 10:49:36 socat[7405] E connect(16, AF=2 127.0.0.1:88, 16): Connection refused
E0523 12:49:36.847735   16200 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 58193 88: error forwarding port 88 to pod 764194941a96bf6dc7b3d491ffe910cd34885e20a0b98690392b9a4c4feca310, uid : exit status 1: 
2022/05/23 10:49:36 socat[7406] E connect(16, AF=2 127.0.0.1:88, 16): Connection refused
E0523 12:49:36.884999   16200 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
Handling connection for 58193
E0523 12:49:36.885522   16200 portforward.go:391] error copying from local connection to 
remote stream: EOF
E0523 12:49:36.888639   16200 portforward.go:346] error creating error stream for port 
58193 -> 88: EOF
```

I don't know what to do to access the nginx app I created in my browser and i cant find any doc.

Comment: Run kubectl get services my-service. There you will find a field as Loadbalancer Ingress with the external IP of your nginx server. Also, there are 2 ports, Port and NodePort. Access your application as http://<external_IP_from_ingress_loadbalancer>:<Port>

Comment: It doesn't work. It still says that localhost (the external ip) doesnt authorize the connection.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found what the problem was, I had opened docker and kubernetes on my admin session but was accessing it from a browser on my normal session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).